# I have a bunch of colorants, what are the properties I need to know about them to predict the LAB values of the resultant mixture?

Tags: color-theory, color-reproduction, ink

Let's say I have a bunch of colorants/paints in liquid form and my job is to mix them together. After mixing, I will have to take a sample, spray-paint it on a metal substrate, dry it, and then examine the resultant Hunter-LAB values with a Konica-Minolta Chroma Meter.

Is it possible, if I have full knowledge of the specifications of these colorants/paints, to mathematically predict the final Hunter-LAB value of their mixture? Specifications as in:

1. Weight in kg of colorants used
2. Their LAB values upon spray-painting
3. Their tinting strength

Etc. etc.

If yes, what are the important specifications I need to know about my colourants before I can mathematically predict (using equations/formulas) the resultant LAB values?

If no, why is it not possible?

Thanks in advance!